Is there a way to make a cancelable off-thread function in python?
I am having a lot of trouble trying to create a function that acts as an input when called in a thread and can be cancelled at any time. This function would still return a value when called using a thread. I did some testing on a module that does not have an input call.
I tried using the multiprocessing module, but there were a few issues I came across:

If I used multiprocessing.Process, it would be able to be terminated, but I couldn't get the output.

If I used multiprocessing.pool, it would return the value, but I couldn't find a way to terminate it.


Is there a way to possibly combine Process and pool to make it work? I haven't worked with multiprocessing much and I need guidance on how to fully implement the methods above.
My code should go something like:
from threading import Thread
import time
def inp(prompt):
    return input(prompt)

def stop():
    time.sleep(1)
    # close the thread

t=Thread(target=inp,args=['Enter your name: '])
t2=Thread(target=stop) # Simulate cancelling the input thread
t.start()
t2.start()

# Get the value of the return statement of t


The right way to do this is to have the thread monitor a flag that tells it to exit.  It's never completely safe to force-terminate a thread or process.  With processes, you can always send a signal.

@peter Your comment is only telling me the proper way to quit threads and processes, and it does not actually address the question. The reason that I made this post wasn't to ask how to terminate them correctly, it was to ask how to implement the techniques of returning values and terminating it at will - or to ask for simply other suggestions of how I could do both an alternate way.

I thought it was obvious.  With threads, you can set global die = False, have your thread do while not die:, and when its time is up, do global die / die = True.

@JohnDavis2 The available solutions depend a lot on exactly what the function does (e.g. io-bound vs cpu-bound) and how it does it (e.g. one step vs multiple steps, or serial vs parallel). There's no generic solution that will be equally effective in all cases. You should therefore edit your question and show a much more realistic test function that more accurately reflects your actual code.

Okay, so if your question really is about reading keyboard input with input(), that's an entirely different thing, and much harder, since the input() call simply will block and cannot be interrupted.

Could you use signal to force-quit the thread even if input blocks termination?

In Python, there is no way to terminate a thread from outside itself - the thread itself has to do so (by returning or raising an exception from any functions it is running).
A function running in a sub-process, on the other hand, can be killed along with that process. Getting a value back from  a subprocess, although, as you perceived, requires a lot of boilerplate, and while multiprocessing.Pool and concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor have the code to make the correct communication with a subprocess, this same "correct code" will wait for any running tasks in the remote process to finish before killing it - as you also noted (in some quick tets I noted here, it is even worse: it wait for the tasks, can't read the result back, and the termination call itself hangs).
All in all, you'd have to setup the interprocess communication yourself, and have at least 2 threads in the remote process: one executing your function, and one checking for a poison pill message and exit everything.
The usual pattern for what you called an input function is a producer function, which would not have to produce one single value, but produce repeated values. Then, at each value produced, it could check for messages, and see if it should terminate itself. This pattern is implementable with queues - and could be done with a single thread in the remote process.
On the other hand, since you want a Cancellable function and don't need another process, just a way to cancel your running function, you should just use asynchronous programming (e.g. using the asyncio library) instead.
Unlike tasks running in worker threads or processes, asynchronous tasks can be killed anytime by just calling their cancel() method. The only thing is that they have to yield control to the event loop periodically, so it can check if a cancellation took place. This is done anytime there is an await expression - which occurs naturally if you are waiting for I/O, like networking results or database query responses using an async-aware library - otherwise, for CPU intensive code, you will have to call await asyncio.sleep(0) from time to time.
if you aren't switching all your code to be async based, it is possible to have just your producer function as async, along with another function which can check for cancelation, and one small synchronous function to get things running:
# async code for a cancellable, off-thread, returnable, function

import asyncio
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue, Empty

async def foo(bar, baz):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("done {bar}")
    return "foo " + baz

async def asyncmain(input_queue, out_queue, *args):
    worker_task = asyncio.create_task(foo(*args))
    while True:
        try:
            message = input_queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            message = False
        if message == "cancel":
            worker_task.cancel()
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            return
        if worker_task.done():
            out_queue.put(worker_task.result())
            return
        # no need to pool continuously for cancel tasks - 
        # give some rest time:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.02)

def mycode(wait=3):
    command_queue = Queue()
    result_queue = Queue() 
    worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(asyncmain(command_queue, result_queue, "world", "foo"),))
    worker_thread.start()
    time.sleep(wait) # variable waiting time, so we can test cancelation
    command_queue.put("cancel")
    try:
        result = result_queue.get_nowait() 
    except Empty:
        result = None
    worker_thread.join()
    print(f"Got {result!r} back")



And if called with times above 5 second, you get the answer, otherwise, the task is cancelled after the wait is over.
As stated above, the one thing to actually be aware is that the worker code have to pass the control back to the event loop from time to time. In this case, we use the  await asyncio.sleep call. "Real world" code will usually await a call to an async function which performs I/O.  If whatever you are running for you have no async version, then use an await asyncio.to_thread(target_function) to run that call in yet another thread. (it won't be cancelled and will run to conclusion under the hood if your worker is cancelled, but it will be automatically cleaned up)

If you really want to read the keyboard as in input, asyncio can also help: the terminedia library have a seamless ainput which can be called as co-routine, and can be straight-forward cancelled - (just replace the call to foo for terminedia.ainput in the code above. You can install terminedia with pip install terminedia (disclaimer: I am its author and maintainer).

Turns out OP really does want to mess with input() after all...

I have found a solution based off of this answer. Thanks for the help!

Oh - if you really want input in the end, I have authored this lib which features an ainput : an input which can be called as a co-routine, and cancelled in an asyncio context. I'just updated the code to mention it.
